# Probability question in Harvard Stat110 Homework1 on course time slots overlapping

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A college has 10 (non-overlapping) time slots for its courses, and blithely assigns courses to time slots randomly and independently. A student randomly chooses 3 of the courses to enroll in (for the PTP, to avoid getting fined). What is the probability that there is a conflict in the student’s schedule?

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zu8c.png)

The solution provided uses complement to solve this question, what is wrong with my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability of conflict is complement of not having conflict. Which is $$\frac{10\times 9 \times 8}{10^3}=0.72$$
The way you have done it is a little off. Ways of having two confilcts is you can have 3 ways in which the courses having conflict can be selected. The time slot of one of the courses can be chosen in 10 ways and the next two courses in 9 ways. So that is $3\times9\times10=270.$ Now 3 conflicts can be chosen in $10$ ways. Because once you choose the first course all the courses should be in the same slot. So that total is $280$ ways. So the probability of clash is $0.28$.

Comment: Can you explain why it's 10^3?

Comment: You can map this question as having 3 bags, each with 10 numbered balls inside, from 1 to 10. As if each course was a bag and each numbered ball was a time slot. So, by picking one ball from each bag, there are 10^3 possible outcomes.