# STAT 110 over-lapping courses

Tags: probability, combinatorics

so I came across this post: [Probability question in Harvard Stat110 Homework1 on course time slots overlapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789571/probability-question-in-harvard-stat110-homework1-on-course-time-slots-overlappi?rq=1) and I tried to understand why there is 10*9*3 +1 0 in the numerator but I cant find a reason for the 3 instead of a 2. So here is what I think:

For the first course, we have 10 choices, for the second 9 (s.t. it is not the same as the first) and for the third I imagine that we have two different choices (either in course 1 or in course 2). I understand why we have to add 10 in order to account for the possibilities that all three choices conflict, but I do not understand the 3 in the numerator.

Could someone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have $10$ letters $\{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J\}$ and you have to choose $3$ among them such that exactly $2$ are same then. Then by your logic (i.e you choose a letter then you choose another one and then you choose one among the 2 previously chosen letter, so the total ways by this logic comes out to be $5*4*2$ ) you'll miss out all the permutations of type $\{X,X,Y\} $ i.e the first and second letter is the same but the last is not.

Hence the right way to do this task is to choose a letter then choose another one and blindly place the same letter in the third slot too, and then reorder it in all possible ways ${\frac{3!}{2!}}$. So, the right approach would give you $5*4*{\frac{3!}{2!}}$.

Which explains why there is a ${\frac{3!}{2!}} = 3$ instead of $2$ in the answer

Comment: So basically, the right way to think about this is to think of the 5 as the random letter, the 4 is the letter that is contained twice and 3 choose 2 is the amount of how many different arangements there are? I thought n choose k is for checking how many unordered sets there are in n with size k? Why is this equivalent to the amount of different permutations?

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent because it includes all types of possibilities (X, X, Y), (X, Y, X) and (Y, X, X) for X and Y from the 10 letters such that X is not equal to Y.

Comment: Okay, but why? I imagine 3 choose 2 as having {A,B,C} and you get {(A,B),(B,C),(A,C)}. Why is this equivalent to all possible combinations of {X,X,Y} ?

Comment: Hey, slip of typo from my side it should be ${\frac{3!}{2!}}$ and NOT $3 \choose 2$. I hope you get why... Although both equals 3 in this case. It will not in general.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. Now it actually makes sense to me.