# Why is it 10*9*8 and not 10 choose 3?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

A college has 10 (non-overlapping) time slots for its courses, and blithely assigns
courses to time slots randomly and independently. A student randomly chooses 3 of
the courses to enroll in (for the PTP, to avoid getting fined). What is the probability
that there is a conflict in the student’s schedule?

Solution: The probability of no conflict is $\frac{10·9·8}{10^3} = 0.72$. So the probability of there being
at least one scheduling conflict is 0.28.

Shouldn't the numerator be $\binom{10}{3} = \frac{10*9*8}{3!}$ because we don't care about the order of the time slots. For example, if 1,2,3 are time slots that don't conflict, then isn't that the same as 2,1,3? And so we must divide by 3! because order doesn't matter?

Comment: The short answer is that the denominator is counting the number of possible time slots that could be assigned to student course 1, student course 2, and student course 3 _in order_, so the numerator needs to count the number of (non-)conflicts when those courses are ordered.

Comment: the order of the time slots *does* matter. When you are calculating the probability of no conflict, you assume which time slot is being used first, then proceed on second and third.

Answer (score 1):

This is a similar problem to this question asked:
[Probability question in Harvard Stat110 Homework1 on course time slots overlapping](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789571)

The reason is that the order matters is because they are not the same classes, they are all different from each other. Taking classes 1, then 2, then 3 would be a different schedule than 3, 2, then 1. That is why you don't divide by the 3!. I hope this helps.